# Method inside fragment is called just before fragment is created, throwing a NPE. How should I handle this?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to hide/show an action bar button basically "on command". I have to do this from different fragments inside my app, so I created a method for toggling the button in the fragment where the button is located.

As you can see below, I call the method `addSMVFFragments` inside the fragment as soon as the fragment is selected from the navigation drawer, which then calls the `disableDeleteAllButton` method. Because of this, the fragment isn't created yet when the `disableDeleteAllButton` method is called, which throws a `NPE`.

How can I work around this? Can I 'delay' the call of `disableDeleteAllButton`, so the fragment has time to be created (Seems like a bad idea to me)? Should I do something else? All help is greatly appreciated.

(All code is simplified for easy reading, so if parts seem to be missing, they probably are there in the complete code. If you prefer to see the entire set of code, let me know.)

Main_Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    isMainShown = false;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_stuffmanager) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new StuffManagerFragment(), getString(R.string.navdrawer_stuffmanager)).commit();
        setTitle(getString(R.string.navdrawer_stuffmanager));
        addSMVFFragments();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void addSMVFFragments(){
    StuffManagerFragment.disableDeleteAllButton(true);
}
```

StuffManagerFragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.stuffmanager_actionbuttons, menu);
    optionsMenu = menu;
}

....

public static void disableDeleteAllButton(boolean bool) {
    optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.removeAllButton).setVisible(!bool);
}
```

Log:

```
03-01 02:07:49.390 15748-15748/com.example.tim.timapp I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-01 02:07:49.460 15748-15748/com.example.tim.timapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.tim.timapp-2/lib/x86_64
03-01 02:07:49.650 15748-15777/com.example.tim.timapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-01 02:07:49.690 15748-15777/com.example.tim.timapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-01 02:07:49.750 15748-15777/com.example.tim.timapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-01 02:07:49.750 15748-15777/com.example.tim.timapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f63f316cd80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-01 02:08:06.360 15748-15748/com.example.tim.timapp D/TEST: Fragment not ready
03-01 02:08:16.270 15748-15748/com.example.tim.timapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-01 02:08:16.270 15748-15748/com.example.tim.timapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tim.timapp, PID: 15748
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference
at com.example.fragments.Settings.StuffManagerFragment.disableDeleteAllButton(StuffManagerFragment.java:98)
at com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity.addSMVFFragments(MainActivity.java:209)
at com.example.tim.timapp.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:191)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:150)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:84)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:308)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Since the `disableDeleteAllButton` is static the `optionsMenu` is probably also static. Having either as static is not a good idea. Why don't you pass the desired visibility for the delete button to the fragment as an argument? If you need to update the value later it would be best to find the fragment by id or tag and call an instance method on it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I'm not very familiar with passing arguments to fragments and instance methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out, thanks to [Silambarasan Poonguti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1799145/silambarasan-poonguti)'s push in the right direction, combined with [Francesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2741273/francesc)'s suggestion.

What I ended up doing, is setting a `public boolean` called `hideDeleteAllButton` (Sorry for the random name change, inconsitency sucks, I know) inside the `StuffManagerFragment`, which is the fragment that contains the button itself.

Using the method I describe below, I'm not getting any errors anymore, and stuff works as intended. This does however by no means mean that this is the best, or even a correct, way of doing this. So if you have more knowledge about this stuff, and see some errors I made, please tell me. I'll be glad to investigate and fix stuff.
Also, it's very possible that I forgot something in this answer, since I've been coding the entire day, and I'm having trouble seeing everything clearly. If you feel like something's missing, tell me, and I'll fix it.

---

### Basics

We're gonna use `invalidateOptionsMenu()` with this solution. If I'm correct, this requires (calls) `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` inside the fragment.

My `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.removeAllButton).setVisible(!hideDeleteAllButton);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

---

### Inside the fragment

Inside the `StuffManagerFragment`, changing the buttons state is as easy as setting `hideDeleteAllButton` to either true or false, based on what you need, and then call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on `getActivity()`.

```
hideDeleteAllButton = true;
getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

---

### From other fragments

From another fragment, you first have to initiate the fragment that contains the variable, so in my case, you initiate `StuffManagerFragment`. This is done right after defining the class.

```
public class #OtherFragmentName# extends 

    StuffManagerFragment f = new StuffManagerFragment();
    ....
```

`f` is a random name, you can assign any name here.

Now, you have to set the variable to either `false` or `true`, by calling `f.hideDeleteAllButton = true;` (or false obviously). After that, again call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on `getActivity()`.

```
f.hideDeleteAllButton = false;
getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Don't forget, if you chose a different name from `f`, you'll have to use `#YourChosenName#.hideDeleteAllButton = true;`.
This bit of code can be called from anywhere, like in an onClick method.

Comment: I think I like the idea of this approach more overall. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

The fragment is added asynchronously, so you cannot call APIs on it immediately after adding it to the stack (fragmentManager.replace) because it is not initialized (it has not gone through inflation yet). You should pass a variable to the fragment via a factory method, and that variable will instruct the fragment to show or hide the menu option.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work 100%. I need this button to change appearance on the fly, not just when the fragment is loaded, so the change in variable should also invoke some code that actually changes the button appearance.

Answer (score 1):

**optionsMenu** object has NULL reference so its throwing NPE.

You don't need to override **onCreateOptionsMenu()** in your Fragment class again. Menu items visibility can be changed by overriding **onPrepareOptionsMenu()** method available in Fragment class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  menu.findItem(R.id.removeAllButton).setVisible(false);
  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Some questions though:
1. I'm unsure about what @Override does (not a lot of experience in android dev yet, a link to an explanation would be appreciated, so I can understand why it's not needed).
2. How or when would onPrepareOptionsMenu be called? I need this button to change appearance on the fly, not just when the fragment is loaded.

Comment: Answer for 1st question: onCreateOptionsMenu() is called once your Activity created, On other hand onPrepareOptionsMenu() is called every time the menu opens. you do not need to override onCreateOptionsMenu() again in activity.

Comment: Ah, right. The problem is however, that I don't use the options menu, I use action buttons (should've stated that more clearly). They are part of the options menu, but are always visible (if there's room).